Why is $\sup A-\epsilon<a$ rather than $\sup A-\epsilon\leq a$ for any $\epsilon>0$?
Why is $\sup A - \epsilon < a$ for some $a \in A$? Why isn't it $\sup A - \epsilon \leq a$?
I'm talking about a specific case where $A$ is an open interval, for example $A =(0,1)$. It feels like if $1$ is the $\sup A$, then if I subtract an "infinitely small" $\epsilon$ from it, it should equal a number which is infinitely close to $1$ but not equal to $1$. Therefore, there wouldn't be an $a \in A$ higher than it.
There is no such number though, and if there was, it would be the supremum of  A meaning $\sup A - \epsilon = \sup A$, therefore $\epsilon = 0$, right? Is that how to disprove this?

First, it should be $\epsilon\gt 0$, not $\epsilon\lt 0$. Second, please use MathJax throughout, including the title.

That's why we don't consider "infinitely small" numbers in usual Calculus, it just makes things confusing. In this case, $\epsilon$ denotes a real positive number, not a infinitely small real number, since there's no such thing.

Your conjecture is on the right track: In the real numbers, there’s no such thing as an “infinitely small” $\epsilon$ - if it’s non-negative, then it’s some perhaps small but positive quantity (there is some positive rational number $< \epsilon$). The answer by @MKhaled explains it well. “Infinitesimal” values are possible in the hyperreal numbers, but not in the real numbers.

Recall, an upper bound for a set $A$ is a real number $l$ such that for all $a\in A$, $a\leq l$.
If $A$ is a set bounded above, then for every $\epsilon>0$, $\mathrm{sup}(A)-\epsilon$ is not an upper bound for $A$. So, there exists $a\in A$ such that $\mathrm{sup}(A)-\epsilon<a$.

Of course, thank you

Fix $\epsilon > 0$.  You can think of $\epsilon$ as "small" if you want, but "infinitely small" doesn't make sense, as you've said.  Anyway, you're correct that there exists $a \in A$ such that $\sup(A) - \epsilon \leq a$.
However, it's also true that there exists an $a \in A$ such that $\sup(A) - \epsilon < a$.  The reason is that, as M Khaled Bin-Lateef points out, $\sup(A) - \epsilon$ is less than $\sup(A)$, the least upper bound of $A$.  Therefore, $\sup(A) - \epsilon$ is not an upper bound of $A$, which by definition means that some $a \in A$ satisfies $\sup(A) - \epsilon < a$.

Ok thanks. I'm just trying to build an intuition. I "intuited" that the difference between (0,1) and (0,1] is just a single point which could be covered by some epsilon>0. That doesn't make sense though, right?

It's true that $(0,1]$ is just $(0,1)$ together with one more point.  However, both $(0,1)$ and $(0,1]$ have a supremum of $1$.

What is the definition of $\sup$?
Given a nonempty subset $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ of the real numbers which is also bounded, one defines $\sup(A)$ as the smallest upper bound of $A$, which is unique (why?). But what is the definition of upper bound? We say that $U\in\mathbb{R}$ is an upper bound for the set $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ iff $x\leq U$ for every $x\in A$. Hence $U$ is not an upper bound for $A$ iff there exists $x\in A$ such that $x > U$.
Consequently, since $\sup(A) - \varepsilon$ is not an upper bound for $A$ when $\varepsilon > 0$, one concludes there exists some $x\in A$ such that $\sup(A) - \varepsilon < x$
